# Python checkbox tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня не получается изменить данные Сheckbutton и тем самым не получается кофигурировать остальные элементы. Вот код:

```
def change(event):
       def change_state(event):
              print(cvar.get())
              if cvar.get()==True:
                     colors_2.config(state = NORMAL)
                     lab_fr_2.config(state = NORMAL)
              elif cvar.get() == False:
                     colors_2.config(state = DISABLED)
                     lab_fr_2.config(state = DISABLED)
       cvar = BooleanVar()
       cvar.set(0)
       select = lbox.curselection()
       tag = lbox.get(select)
       change_window = Tk()
       change_window.title('Изменить '+tag)
       l_fr = LabelFrame(change_window, text='Изменить координаты')
       l_fr_2 = LabelFrame(change_window, text = 'Изменить внешний вид')
       first = Frame(l_fr)
       second = Frame(l_fr)
       c_x1 = Label(first, text="x1: ", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))
       c_x1.pack(padx = 5, side = LEFT)
       e_c_x1 = Entry(first, width = 3, font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))
       e_c_x1.pack(padx = 5, side = LEFT)
       c_y1 = Label(first, text="y1: ", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))
       c_y1.pack(padx = 5, side = LEFT)
       e_c_y1 = Entry(first, width = 3, font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))
       e_c_y1.pack(padx = 5, side = LEFT)
       first.pack(pady = 2)
       c_x2 = Label(second, text="x2: ", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))
       c_x2.pack(padx = 5, side = LEFT)
       e_c_x2 = Entry(second, width = 3, font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))
       e_c_x2.pack(padx = 5, side = LEFT)
       c_y2 = Label(second, text="y2: ", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))
       c_y2.pack(padx = 5, side = LEFT)
       e_c_y2 = Entry(second, width = 3, font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))
       e_c_y2.pack(padx = 5, side = LEFT)
       second.pack(pady = 2)
       l_fr.pack()
       ff = Frame(l_fr_2)
       sf = Frame(l_fr_2)
       lab_fr = Label(ff, text = 'Цвет обводки: ',  font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))
       colors = t.Combobox(ff, values = ["красный","оранжевый","жёлтый", "зелёный","голубой","синий", "фиолетовый", "белый", "чёрный"])
       colors.set("чёрный")
       ch = Checkbutton(l_fr_2, text = 'Заливка',  variable=cvar, onvalue=True, offvalue=0) 
       ch.bind('<Button-1>', change_state)
       lab_fr_2 = Label(sf, text = 'Цвет заливки: ',  font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14), state = DISABLED)
       colors_2 = t.Combobox(sf, values = ["красный","оранжевый","жёлтый", "зелёный","голубой","синий", "фиолетовый", "белый", "чёрный"], state = DISABLED)
       colors_2.set("белый")
       ff.pack()
       sf.pack()
       l_fr_2.pack()
       lab_fr.pack(side = LEFT)
       colors.pack(side = LEFT)
       ch.pack()
       lab_fr_2.pack(side=LEFT)
       colors_2.pack(side = LEFT)
       change_window.mainloop()
```

Помогите изменить значение Чекбокса!

Comment: А что нужно делать с чекбоксом и что не работает? Кст, можете вопрос дополнить кодом (кнопка `править`), чтобы любой мог скопировать его из вопроса, запустить?

Comment: Запустил ваш пример и заметил что в `cvar.get()` значения инвертированные -- у `Checkbutton` стоит флажок, в `cvar.get()` возвращает False и наоборот. У вас с этим была проблема?

Comment: нет. Не зря для проверки поставил print(char.get()). У меня постоянно принтуется False

Comment: Зря, не зря, мало ли для чего вы ставили `print` :) Это нужно в вопросе описывать, подробнее чтобы люди не гадали :)

Answer (score 1):

Убрал биндинг к событию:

```
ch.bind('<Button-1>', change_state)
```

И в конструкторе `Checkbutton` указал функцию в качестве команды:

```
ch = Checkbutton(l_fr_2, text='Заливка', variable=cvar, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, command=change_state)
```

Весь минимальный код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


def change_state():
    if cvar.get():
        colors_2.config(state=NORMAL)
        lab_fr_2.config(state=NORMAL)
    else:
        colors_2.config(state=DISABLED)
        lab_fr_2.config(state=DISABLED)


change_window = Tk()
change_window.geometry('300x300+200+200')
change_window.title('Изменить ')

cvar = BooleanVar()
cvar.set(False)

l_fr_2 = LabelFrame(change_window, text='Изменить внешний вид')

ch = Checkbutton(l_fr_2, text='Заливка', variable=cvar, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, command=change_state)
lab_fr_2 = Label(l_fr_2, text='Цвет заливки: ', font=("Comic Sans MS", 14), state=DISABLED)
colors_2 = Combobox(l_fr_2, values=["красный", "оранжевый", "жёлтый", "зелёный", "голубой", "синий", "фиолетовый", "белый", "чёрный"], state=DISABLED)
colors_2.set("белый")

l_fr_2.pack()
ch.pack()
colors_2.pack(side=LEFT)

change_window.mainloop()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё равно ничего. По прежнему только False.

Comment: @Егор, в моем коде нет постоянного `False`. Попробуйте код погонять и посмотреть чем у вас принципиально отличается. А что у вас там наворочено сказать не могу -- от вас нужен [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), а чем я и просил в комментарии вопроса

Comment: Я догадался почему у вас всё работает а у меня нет. Вы это окно вызвали в основном коде программы, а я в функции. Иначе не могу. Это вспомогательное окно, помимо его там ещё много таких.

Comment: @Егор, это объясняет зачем вам `def change(event):` ) Обернул код из ответа в `def foo()` и вызвал `foo()` пару раз -- сначала одно окно появилось, после закрытия -- другое. Клики по checkbutton возвращают правильные значения, но не думаю, они не должны были быть синхронными... Наверное дело в том что используются Tk, а не Toplevel

Comment: Но мне нужно именно использования Tk()

Comment: @Егор, дочерние окна должны создаваться через `Toplevel`, а не `Tk`, иначе привязанные переменные работать не будут, см. вот этот вопрос: [Не изменяется поле IntVar() в классе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929706/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-intvar-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5/929727)